# Finding IP address of physical machine when in a remote session

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, ip

I have looked around stackoverflow, but all it describes is how to get a remote IP address when you're working remote. That can be done doing the following:

```
var ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty);
var ipAddressList = ipHostEntry.AddressList;
var ipv4Addresses = Array.FindAll(ipAddressList, a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
result = ipv4Addresses[0].ToString();
```

Where `result` is the remote IP address (or the local one, depending on whether or not you're working remote).

However, I want the following:

- I am working remote (using RDP)
- I need the IP of the physical machine (the computer that is running RDP to connect to another machine), not the remote machine

Is there any way to accomplish this using C#?

Comment: What do you mean by "working remote"  ? are you connected via RDP ? and by "IP of the physical machine" you mean IP of the RDP client

Comment: if it's a RDP then PInvoke  `WTSQuerySessionInformation` should do the thing ... **edit:** also quick googling: `C# getting RDP client IP` returns lots of information

Comment: I have updated my question. It was indeed RDP. I will look into it

Answer (score 1):

I read many many lines of codes and went through many documentation pages, but this helped me solve it: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111430/Grabbing-Information-of-a-Terminal-Services-Sessio

The above helps you get a list of all sessions and their corresponding IP addresses. However, if you have many RDP connections to one remote server, then you'll want to get the IP address of your specific client, I solved that like this:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
static extern int GetCurrentProcessId();

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
static extern int ProcessIdToSessionId(int dwProcessid, ref int pSessionId);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS
{
    public int iAddressFamily;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    public byte[] bAddress;
}

private static string GetIpAddressFromSession(int sessionId, IntPtr server)
{
    var ipAddress = string.Empty;
    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(server, sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientAddress, out IntPtr ipAddressPointer, out uint returnedBytes) == true)
    {
        var clientAddress = new WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS();
        clientAddress = (WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipAddressPointer, clientAddress.GetType());

        ipAddress = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", clientAddress.bAddress[2], clientAddress.bAddress[3], clientAddress.bAddress[4], clientAddress.bAddress[5]);
    }

    return ipAddress;
}

public static string GetLocalIpAddressWhileRemote()
{
    var ipAddress = string.Empty;
    var processId = GetCurrentProcessId();
    var sessionId = 0;
    var hasFoundSessionId = ProcessIdToSessionId(processId, ref sessionId) != 0;
    if (hasFoundSessionId)
    {
        ipAddress = GetIpAddressFromSession(sessionId, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    return ipAddress;
}
```

First, you get the `processId` of your client and use that to get the `sessionId`. With the `sessionId` you can then use `WTSQuerySessionInformation` with the `WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientAddress` parameter to get the session IP-address. I have not included the WTS_INFO_CLASS enum, you will still have to add this yourself for it to work.